# Existential type as a return type

Tags: scala

So I have a trait that looks something like this.

```
trait Foo[Bar <: Baz[_]] {
   def qux: X = ???
}
```

Ideally, what I want is to be able to control the return type of my `qux` by the generic type of my `Baz`. I.e. this

```
trait Foo[Bar <: Baz[Y]] {
   def qux: Y = ???
}
```

I've researched some topics but I can't seem to stumble upon the right thing, possibly because I'm not familiar enough with the terminology. Is this achievable by some syntax I'm missing or do I need to rethink my approach?

Comment: Would it not work for you if you introduced `Y` as a proper type param: `trait Foo[Y, Bar <: Baz[Y]]`?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yeah, it would. I'm trying to see if there's any way to avoid that. I feel it should be redundant to specify that type in two places when I already know that it's specified through my `Bar`

Comment: @bjornnes it is not redundant, `Bar` hasn't specified what is the type of `Baz`, it says for any type. - Now, there may be ways to avoid users typing both.